# control nested mixin behavior based on parent mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Here are two mixins

```
@mixin parent {
  .parent & {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin child($child) {
  .#{$child} & {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Both mixin works fine independently.

Things which am looking for:

1. **child** can be independent
2. Also **child** mixin can be included in **parent** but opposite
   should not be allowed.
3. In case someone tries to include **parent** into **child** there should
   be some error message.
4. In css output `.parent` should come before `.child`*(see example below for this point)*

Point 4 example:

```
.test {
  //some css properties
  @include parent {
    @include child(childboy) {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

*as you can see this will give following output*

```
.childboy .parent .test {
  color: red;
}
```

As you can see `.parent` class is coming after `.childboy`.

How can we make it `.parent` class to come before `.childboy`

```
.parent .childboy .test {
  color: red;
}
```

**Is it possible to do with scss??**
Please answer only in scss.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why do you need such complicated behavior. I bet, in a couple of months you can not answer how this code works and how it should work. If you need such designs, most likely, you are doing something wrong. Try to keep the simplicity of css. This is not a programming language.

Comment: @3rdthemagical scss provide great functionalities, there are so many insane things one can do with scss. I am just figuring out the possibilities with scss.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it that way.

Check out [this CSS-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-9):

> The `&` doesn't allow you to selectively traverse up your nested
>   selector tree to a certain place and only use a small portion of the
>   compiled parent selector that you want to use.

---

If I understand correctly, the reason why you're trying to do this with SCSS is because you want to group the `.parent .childboy .test` selector within `.test` root selector.

Here's a different way to do this with SASS:

```
.test {
  @at-root .parent .childboy & {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/POLKEG)**

**Note:** the trailing `&` appends the selectors from root downwards - here, just the `.test` class

From the [SASS docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_at-root__at-root):

> The @at-root directive causes one or more rules to be emitted at the
>   root of the document, rather than being nested beneath their parent
>   selectors.